# Attributes initialization/declaration in Python class: where to place them?

Tags: python, coding-style, attributes

I was wondering what was the best practice for initializing object attributes in Python, in the body of the class or inside the `__init__` function?

i.e.

```
class A(object):
    foo = None
```

vs

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.foo = None
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you want the attribute to be shared by all instances of the class, use a class attribute:

```
class A(object):
    foo = None
```

This causes `('foo',None)` to be a `(key,value)` pair in `A.__dict__`.

If you want the attribute to be customizable on a per-instance basis, use an instance attribute:

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.foo = None
```

This causes `('foo',None)` to be a `(key,value)` pair in `a.__dict__` where `a=A()` is an instance of `A`.

Comment: makes sense, I thought they were bounded to the instance in both cases... thanks :)

Comment: Python has a complicated set of [attribute lookup rules](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html). Without getting into descriptors, for this case it suffices to know `a.__dict__` is searched for the `foo` key first, and if it is not found there, then `A.__dict__` is searched. This is why you can use `a.foo` even if `foo` is a class attribute.

Comment: Also noteworthy is that for class attributes, if you were to do `a.foo = whatever`, you'd actually end up creating a new instance attribute (which hides the class attribute). `A.foo` would be unchanged. It's kinda a gotcha, since you can access the value of `A.foo` with `a.foo`, but assigning to that would create a new instance attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Attributes defined in the class definition are considered class variables (like static variables in Java), while those set in the initializer are instance attributes (note the difference between `self.something = 1` and `something = 1`).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python) for more details, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783253/changing-class-variables-in-runtime/7787690#7787690) for even more.  There is not a lot of practical difference between these two cases, as the class-level definition gives the attribute a default value, but if you want to use some kind of logic to set an attribute before using an object instance you should do it in the `__init__()` method.