# Add CSS class to entire form in Django

Tags: python, css, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget

Suppose I have a form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    ...
```

and then in a view I construct it:

```
...
form = MyForm()
...
```

I would like to add a CSS class to the entire form, so that I can render it as something like this:

```
<form class="{{ form.CLASS }}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What is the proper way to achieve that (other than define a field "class")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an attribute in your form, by override the `__init__` method, like what I've done here: [Override defaults attributes of a Django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020227/override-defaults-attributes-of-a-django-form/18020298#18020298) :)

You can name the attribute class_name for example, and initialize your form by `form = MyForm(class_name="myCssClass")`