# Override the initialization of a ChoiceField in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to initialize a form containing a `ChoiceField` in django. I have the following code:

```
# in file models.py
class Locality(models.Model):
    locality = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=36)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.locality

# in file forms.py
class RegisterForm(forms.Form): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
        self.locality = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select())
        self.fields['locality'].choices = [l.locality for l in Locality.objects.all()]
```

but oon the shell, once I try to instanciate:

> > > r = RegisterForm(username="toto", email="a@b.com")

I receive `'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'fields' error`. Is this happening as the object is not already formed? How can I access to the `ChoiceField`?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You're not using the `Form` object in the good way. The `fields` attribute is initialize [by the `__init__` method of BaseForm (see the source code)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L74) (a parent class of `forms.Form`), but you have redefine it, so you broke the process.

So, you should call the parent `__init__` in your `__init__` method, something like this:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form): 
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    locality = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['locality'].choices = [(l.id, l.locality) for l in Locality.objects.all()]
```

I have moved every `*Field` declaration outside the `__init__`, because it's the common way. It's question is very similar to a previous one: [Override defaults attributes of a Django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020227/override-defaults-attributes-of-a-django-form/18020298#18020298)

Comment: Updated, just before I see your comment

Comment: `self.fields['locality'].choices = [l.locality for l in Locality.objects.all()]`  is wrong. you must use `self.fields['locality'].choices = [(l.id,l.locality) for l in Locality.objects.all()]` i mean choices must be in format `[(..,..),(..,..),..]`

Comment: You're right, I just copy the line of the author without checking the list comprehension, but the idea is here ;) (Updated again)

Comment: Hello Maxime, thanks for your answer, it sound logical. However forms.Form.__init__ is not a recognized symbol and using the __init__ in BaseForm:

Comment: I have changed my answer with the `super` syntax some minutes ago ;)

Comment: Sorry the text was cut again. Hello Maxime, thanks for your answer, it sound logical. However using your code for instantiating an object r = RegisterForm(username="toto", email="a@b.com") I got an error __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'

Comment: You should do this:  `r = RegisterForm(initial={"username": "toto", "email":"a@b.com"})`. See the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['locality'].choices = [(l.id, l.locality) for l in Locality.objects.all()]
```

Comment: The list will be created at the declaration of the Form. If he adds a new value in Locality after the server has been launched, this new value will not be in the choices list. Instead, the `__init__` function is called every time you instanciate a new form.

Comment: @MaximeLorant  choices must be in format `[(..,..),(..,..),..]`

Comment: @MaximeLorant I am using this methodology in all my projects and it works fine.

Comment: Even if you modify/remove data in `Locality`? Maybe you're right, by looking the class quickly, I see some deepcopy occured... Get some doubts but okay, I remove my downvote :)

Comment: @MaximeLorant yes you are right. i doesn't mean that. i talked about `[(..,..)..`