# Dependency injection on data objects

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I started writing tests for my (python) application and I found dependency injection very helpful. I refactored lot of my code, and it was so easy to write tests. But some classes was tricky.

I have class `Application` which is data structure containing attributes like `name`, `type`, etc. It have also few methods returning somehow modified those attributes. No problem with that, but there is an method `instances` (obviously) returning instances of the application in a form of list of `Process` objects.

```
class Application(object):
    ...
    def instances(self):
        return Processes.all().filtered(lambda process: process.name() == self.name)
```

You can see the dependency on `Processes` class. What should I do?

I have implemented it this way, because when I got an `Application` object from somewhere, I can simply call `a.instances()`, got the list of processes and don't care.

But from testing point of view, I would like to say "hey application, don't search for real processes in the system, look in this mocked processes list".

First possible solution which comes to my mind, was

```
def instances(self, processes=None):
    processes = processes if processes else Processes.all()
    return processes.filtered(...)
```

but it kind of means that probably all of my calls will have specified that argument. And `a.instances(some_processes_list)` is not that pretty as `a.instances()` and may be confusing. Would you consider it as confusing?

What approach or pattern would you recommend please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the processes class as a class attribute:

```
class Application(object):
    process_class = Processes
    ...
    def instances(self):
        return self.process_class.all().filtered(lambda process: process.name() == self.name)
```

And assign a mock class to it (TestProcess) for testing (of course, this new class should implement the method 'all' and return your mock list).

This seems like a quite clear and natural way that doesn't involve patching or adding new methods

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this way too, but it felt unnatural. Because there are lot of `Application` objects and `Processes` class is always same. Even so every application would has its own `Processes` instance.

 Its surely better than what I have right now because it is easily testable, but ...

Comment: It would be a class level attribute. Only the Application class would have the attribute. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809407/attributes-initialization-declaration-in-python-class-where-to-place-them for instance

Comment: Thank you @Alvaro, I've missed that. I am successfully using it, so I have marked your answer as the solution.