# How does Python assign expression to Object Properties?

Tags: php, python, oop

I have been working with PHP for a while and just started with Python. there is a feature in Python that i came across while learning.

**IN Python**

```
class A:
  #some class Properties

class B:
    a = A()  # assiging an expression to the class Property is possible with python.
```

**IN PHP**

```
class A{

}

class B{
  $a = new A();   // PHP does not allow me to do this.

  // I need to do this instead.
  function  __construct(){
    $this->a = new A();
  }
}
```

I would like to know why. How python complies code differently and if there is any way i can do this with PHP.

Comment: The answer to "why" is "because they are completely different languages." If you've been working with PHP for a while, you probably already know the proper PHP way to do it. Writing one language in another never has good results.

Comment: In case of python interpreting the language, it would go level scope based, tries to analyze what has to be initialized when it finds the function scope.

Comment: That's somewhat akin to [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) class variables in PHP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in Python**

Variables declared inside the class definition

```
class A:
  #some class Properties

class B:
    a = A()  # assigning to the class Property
    # class properties are shared across all instances of class B 
    # this is a static property
```

Variables declared inside the class constructor

```
class A:
  #some class Properties

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()  # assigning to the object Property
        # this property is private to this object
        # this is a instance property
```

More reading for python [static and object attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809407/attributes-initialization-declaration-in-python-class-where-to-place-them)

**in PHP**

inPHP, [singleton pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) uses the concept of static variables to share instance across the objects.

Hope this clarifies about class attributes and object attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is language-specific thing. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax)

> ```
> class ClassName:
>     <statement-1>
>     .
>     .
>     .
>     <statement-N>
> ```
>
> Class definitions, like function definitions (def statements) must be executed before they have any effect. (You
>   could conceivably place a class definition in a branch of an if
>   statement, or inside a function.)

As you can see, these expressions are evaluated and you can even use 'if' statement.